# Moq - Parameter mismatch

Tags: moq

I am trying to figure out why I am getting the following exception when Im mocking my very simple interface.

> System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException: Parameter count
>   mismatch.

```
    var zoneLocator = new Mock<IZoneLocator<ZoneInfo>>();
    zoneLocator
        .Setup(zl => zl.GetZoneInfo(
            It.IsAny<double>(), It.IsAny<double>()))
        .Returns((ZoneInfo zoneInfo) =>
            Task.FromResult(zoneInfo));

    var z = zoneLocator.Object.GetZoneInfo(1, 1);
```

interface:

```
public interface IZoneLocator<T>
{
    Task<T> GetZoneInfo(double latitude, double longitude);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The overload of `Returns` that expects a `Func` is expecting a function that has the same inputs as the inputs of your mocked method.  This allows you to alter the return value based on the inputs to the method.

So, to fix this, change your setup to this:

```cs
zoneLocator
    .Setup(zl => zl.GetZoneInfo(It.IsAny<double>(), It.IsAny<double>()))
    .Returns((double latitude, double longitude) =>
        Task.FromResult(/* TODO: create a timezone somehow*/));
```